# Optimizing query and collating results

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, database

I have 2 tables as follows:

```
Table 1
ID  |  Date1  |  Date 2
------------------------
1   | 20180201| 20180201
1   | 20190201| 20190120
1   | 20200201| 20200129
2   | 20200810| 20200731
3   | 20191121| 20191023
3   | 20201030| 20201024
.
.
.

Table 2
ID  |  Tag    |  rel_ID
------------------------
1   | related |  3
1   | related |  8
1   | related |  10
2   | related |  4
2   | related |  5
.
.
.
```

The desired output is as follows:

```
ID|Date1|Date2|rel_ID_1|Date1|Date2|rel_ID_2|Date1|Date2|rel_ID_3|Date1|Date2|Prim ID|Date1|Date 2
1|20200201|20200129|3|20201030|20201024|8|20201104|20201030|10|20200301|20200229|1|20200201|20200129
```

The Date1 and Date 2 fields need to be the max(date1) and max(date2) for both the ID and rel_ID. Once I get this, I will need to decide if the ID or rel_ID is a primary ID based on Date1 being the min value between all the related IDs. 
I have tried multiple sub-queries to achieve this but they take a very long time. Table 2 has around a million rows and Table 1 has 800k rows.
Is this is even possible with just a query? Or would this require a code including SQL's?

A query that I've tried which runs for a very long time is:

```
select t2.ID,t1.date1,t1.date2,t2.rel_ID,rel_date1 = (select max(date1) from t1 where ID = rel_ID), rel_date2 = (select max(date2) from t1 where ID = rel_ID)
from
(select distinct ID,max(date1),max(date2) from t1 group by ID) as t1,
(select distinct ID,rel_ID from t2) as t2
where t1 .ID = t2.ID
```

Comment: Please show us the result that you expect for this sample data.

Comment: Please post a query you tried so far.

Comment: Expected result and a query I tried is posted in the original question

Answer (score 0):

The following might help:

```
select t1.id, min(date1) date1, max(date2) date2
into new_t1
from t1
group by t1.id

select t2.id, t1.date1 date1_min, t1.date2 as date2_max, t2.rel_ID, t1_1.date1, t1_1.date2
into #temp
from t2
left join new_t1 t1 on t1.id = t2.id
left join new_t1 t1_1 on t1_1.id = t2.rel_ID

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((select ',
            max(CASE WHEN [rel_ID]=''' + CAST([rel_ID] as varchar(10)) + ''' then ''' + CAST([rel_ID] as varchar(10)) + ''' end) as [rel_ID],
            max(CASE WHEN [rel_ID]=''' + CAST([rel_ID] as varchar(10)) + ''' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [date1]) ELSE ''0'' END) AS [' + CAST([rel_ID] as varchar(10)) + '_date1],
            max(CASE WHEN [rel_ID]=''' + CAST([rel_ID] as varchar(10)) + ''' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [date2]) ELSE ''0'' END) AS [' + CAST([rel_ID] as varchar(10)) + '_date2]'
            FROM #temp 
            FOR XML PATH(''),type).value('.','varchar(max)'),1,2,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT id, date1_min as date1, date2_max as date2,' + @Cols + '  FROM #temp group by id, date1_min, date2_max' 

print (@query)
exec (@query)
```

[**db<>fiddle demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e9ebb5c5640750e56912a7672d716ae3)